# Wrong results on counting connected blocks with my DFS

Tags: c, matrix, output, depth-first-search

I have a random generated 5 x 5 matrix that consists of 1's and 0's and I'm supposed to find blocks of 1's.

A `1` is a block itself and if it's connected to another `1` from any direction my algorithm is supposed to find all the connected 1's and count them all as one block.

The problem is I cannot get consistent results and sometimes the counter even goes to `-1`.

Here's the [actual code.](http://ideone.com/CCQYkl)

Here's the main, I've removed the randomizing function and just placed an array the program is having trouble with.

```
struct parent {
    int row;
    int col;
}

int ar[5][5] = { 0,0,0,0,1,
                 1,0,0,0,1,
                 0,0,0,0,0,
                 0,0,0,0,0,
                 0,0,0,0,0 };
int countblock=0,num=0;
struct parent pos[30] = { 0 };
srand(time(NULL));
printf("      ---Find the connected blocks---     \n\n");
printf("Creating a random array:\n");
//random5x5(ar);
for (int row = 0, col; row < 5; row++)
{
    for (col = 0; col < 5; col++)
    {
        if (ar[row][col] == 1)
        {
            countblock++;
            ar[row][col] = -1;
            flag = 0;
            check(ar, row, col, pos, &num);
        }
        printf("%d ", ar[row][col]);  // Had problems with this loop not checking 1's
    }  //So I printed them to try to make sure
    printf("\n");
}
printf("\n\n Found the connected blocks! I see only %d of them.", countblock);
return 0;
```

And the DFS function that's supposed to mark 1's it finds in any direction

```
int flag=0; // declared in global

void check(int ar[5][5], int row, int col, struct parent pos[30],int *num){
if (col - 1 >= 0 && row - 1 >= 0)   //Checking Upper-left
{
    if (ar[row - 1][col - 1] == 1) {
        ar[row - 1][col - 1] = -1;
        (*num)+=1;
        pos[*num].row = row; pos[*num].col = col; //Store this position
        check(ar, row - 1, col - 1, pos, num);  //Jump to the found 1
    }
}
if (col - 1 >= 0)       //Checking Left
{
    if (ar[row][col - 1] == 1) {
        ar[row][col - 1] = -1;
        (*num)+=1;
        pos[*num].row = row; pos[*num].col = col;  //Store this position
        check(ar, row, col - 1, pos, num);  //Jump to the found 1
    }
}
if (col - 1 >= 0 && row + 1 <= 4)   //Checking Bottom-Left
{
    if (ar[row + 1][col - 1] == 1) {
        ar[row + 1][col - 1] = -1;
        (*num)+=1;
        pos[*num].row = row; pos[*num].col = col; //
        check(ar, row + 1, col - 1, pos, num); //
    }
}
if (row + 1 <= 4)       //Checking Bottom
{
    if (ar[row + 1][col] == 1) {
        ar[row + 1][col] = -1;
        (*num)+=1;
        pos[*num].row = row; pos[*num].col = col; //
        check(ar, row + 1, col, pos, num); //
    }
}
if (col + 1 <= 4 && row + 1 <= 4)   //Checking Bottom-Right
{
    if (ar[row + 1][col + 1] == 1) {
        ar[row + 1][col + 1] = -1;
        (*num)+=1;
        pos[*num].row = row; pos[*num].col = col; //
        check(ar, row + 1, col + 1, pos, num); //
    }
}
if (col + 1 <= 4)       //Checking Right
{
    if (ar[row][col + 1] == 1) {
        ar[row][col + 1] = -1;
        (*num)+=1;
        pos[*num].row = row; pos[*num].col = col; //
        check(ar, row, col + 1, pos, num); //
    }
}
if (col + 1 <= 4 && row - 1 >= 0)      //Checking Upper-Right
{
    if (ar[row - 1][col + 1] == 1) {
        ar[row - 1][col + 1] = -1;
        (*num)+=1;
        pos[*num].row = row; pos[*num].col = col; //
        check(ar, row - 1, col + 1, pos, num); //
    }
}
if (row - 1 >= 0)  //Checking Up
{
    if (ar[row - 1][col] == 1) {
        ar[row - 1][col] = -1;
        (*num)+=1;
        pos[*num].row = row; pos[*num].col = col; //
        check(ar, row - 1, col, pos, num); //
    }
}
if (*num == 0)  //There were no 1's around
    return;
else  //Reached the end of the path, call back
{
    flag++;
    if (flag >= 2) //On first call back the pos is still on parent call
        (*num)-=1;  // On second call it should go back
    check(ar, pos[*num].row, pos[*num].col, pos, num);
}
```

**EDIT :** Here's the error

```
flag++;
    if (flag >= 2) //On first call back the pos is still on parent call
        (*num)-=1;  // On second call it should go back
    check(ar, pos[*num].row, pos[*num].col, pos, num);
```

Fixed it by making it

```
flag++;
    if (flag >= 2)
        (*num)-=1;
    if (*num == 0)
        return;
    check(ar, pos[*num].row, pos[*num].col, pos, num);
```

Basically *num would go to zero in `else` and call to the wrong parent location.
Putting another check made it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got some mismatches between the range-checking you do and the neighbours you check. For instance (this is not the only one) look at this:

```
if (row + 1 <= 4)       //Checking Bottom
{
    if (ar[row][col + 1] == 1) {
        ar[row][col + 1] = -1;
        (*num)+=1;
        pos[*num].row = row; pos[*num].col = col; //
        check(ar, row, col + 1, pos, num); //
    }
}
```

You check that `row+1` is in range ... but then you recurse on `col+1`.

This kind of error can result in memory corruption (because you end up writing to locations you didn't mean to), which can make almost anything happen :-).

What happens if you go through checking carefully for this kind of mismatch, fix up any you find, and try again?

Comment: Oh wow I've been tunnel visioning. I've fixed all the mismatches (hastily so will check again after this comment) and updated the code but it still gives wrong results on some arrays.  EDIT: er, let me fix this properly, just excited that I got a comment

Comment: OK. Make sure to update your description of what goes wrong as well as the code in the question :-).

Comment: I really should check my code properly. Now I've actually fixed all the mismatches and it's working fine for all the inputs I try. Will try for some more inputs but thanks for getting me out of tunnel vision.

Comment: You're welcome! This sort of mistake is maddenly easy to make when writing repetetetetetitititititive code. (You can reduce the repetition by e.g. using macros but many people will find the resulting code harder to read.)

Comment: Running the random thing over and over again gave some results, I've simplified the problem array as much as I can in my post, it finds only one box where there are two. I'm really not sure where the problem is, still trying to find it.

Comment: You still have some mismatches -- not now between your range checks and what follows, but between which element of the array you're checking and `-1`-ing and what you pass to your recursive call to `check`. Look e.g. at the "left" case. (There is at least one more; I haven't checked them all.)

Comment: Not enough reputation to chat :( . Anyways I fixed all the functions calls and checked them over and over again to make sure, on rare occasions I get a wrong result but I can't see my error.